# Can't use proxychains because of apparmor

Tags: linux, proxy, root, tor, parrot-os

I was trying to start using proxychains so I first started tor service by typing

```
service tor start
```

tor was started without any errors but when I do

```
proxychains ping www.google.com
```

but that shows up [this-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUCHs.png) but I figured out that this was because I was not root. But when I did `sudo su` and tried to ping google.com, [this-reply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOCdE.png)  showed up. It says it's OK but in my parrot-os, a notification popped up saying [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5utj.png).

It says that the AppArmor denied something and I don't understand what that is. I know that AppArmor is kind of like a firewall to protect incoming and outgoing traffic but I don't understand why it's blocking proxy. Is there any way to add an exception in AppArmor?

My system is Parrot OS 4.10_amd64, Running as bridged adapter in VBOX

here's whats in my [proxychains.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AENgZ.png) file:

```
Strict Chain
socks4 127.0.0.1 9050
socks5 192.111.130.5 4145
```

Comment: Apparmor is used for sandboxing runtimes ensuring that a strict subset of files and resources are accessed and modified during execution. https://wiki.debian.org/AppArmor/HowToUse

Comment: I believe this question might get better feedback if you remove it from here and post it to unix.stackexchange.com